# How can I run a command inside a command in CMake Macro

Tags: bash, shell, cmake, ctest

I want to turn file content into an argument. The argument goes to executable that is being tested. This is what I have

```
ADD_TEST (
    NAME ${ARGV0}
    COMMAND
        ${DIR}/script.sh
        ${executable}\ --arg1\ input
)
```

I want to put the arguments inside a file and feed it to the executable as input. I want something like this:

```
ADD_TEST (
    NAME ${ARGV0}
    COMMAND
        ${DIR}/script.sh
        ${executable}\ $(cat ${ARGS_file})
)
```

Or like this

```
ADD_TEST (
    NAME ${ARGV0}
    COMMAND
        ${DIR}/script.sh
        ${executable}\ `cat ${ARGS_file}`
)
```

Or like this

```
ADD_TEST (
    NAME ${ARGV0}
    COMMAND
        ${DIR}/script.sh
        ${executable}\ $(< ${ARGS_file})
)
```

None of the above three codes works. When I try them outside of CMake, they works fine. but inside CMake they do not work.

Comment: CMake does not use a shell for evaluating the arguments. If you want that behavior and you are sure that you are only operating on linux, you could try something like this:

   COMMAND bash -c "${executable} $(cat ${ARGS_file})"

Like this the evaluation is passed to bash again.

Answer (score 0):

For a more general approach, use `execute_command`, `file(WRITE <path> <contents>)` and then `include(<path>)`.